# n..toString(n) Why does the code return a value of "10"?

Tags: javascript

`(n).toString(n)`  Why does the code return a value of "10"? Where n is number `n <=36` , `n >= 2`

Comment: `SyntaxError: missing name after . operator`

Comment: Had you looked at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString)?  Any number expressed with a radix equal to the number will give you `10`.

Comment: Voting to close as "cannot reproduce".

Comment: This is easily reproduced, but not with the code in the question.  Try using `(12).toString(12)` for instance.

Comment: Are you asking what `.toString(n)` does, or why n in base n is always 10?

Comment: I'm familiar with the documentation. I want why the method returns this result

Comment: the docs tell you. toString(n) is using n as the radix,

Comment: Because that's how [standard positional number notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation) works.

Comment: Do not invent. This syntax works

Comment: `var n=5; n..toString(n);` is invalid syntax. `5..toString(5)` is valid syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the number "12" in base-12?

```
10
```

Why?

The right-most digit is the ones' digit.  The next is the base, 12.  The third digit, if there was one, would be 144.

Repeat, this time with "5" in base-5.

Once again, the second digit is the radix, 5, and the right-most digit is still the one's place.

You can repeat this exercise with any number.  The second digit will always be the radix, by definition, so any number expressed with a radix of itself will always equal 10.

Answer (score 0):

First, `n..toString(n)` is not a valid syntax.  But if you are talking about `n.toString(n)`, the reason is that the param of `toString` is the base that you want to convert your number to.

Every n in the base n is 10. E.g. 9 in the base of 9 is 10, 10 in the base of 9 is 11, etc.

Beside that, the `toString(x)` is defined only for x>=2 and x<=36. You will get a `RangeError` if you try any other value.

Comment: Work this syntax n..toString (n) On the syntax you are offering, swears ide

Comment: To be clear, `5..toString(5)` is valid syntax, it just looks very strange, especially when you keep writing it as a variable instead of a number.  The JS engine interprets the first `.` as a decimal.  Expressed more verbosely, this is `(5.0).toString(5)`.

Comment: Really? I tested it on chrome js terminal, and got an invalid syntax. Maybe it depends on the engine running?

Comment: @GabrielGava yes.  Try it with a number, instead of a variable.  In fact, wrap your head around this:  `5.toString()` *isn't* valid, because the `.` is interpreted as part of the number.  But if you use a variable in place of the `5`, it becomes valid.  Weird, huh.

Comment: Hmm, I see. Thanks for the info. And yes, pretty weird :)